# when are newlines in psql command line strings significant?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I was trying to break a long command line involving `psql` command string (i.e. `psql -c`),and this seems to cause errors. For example, with PostgreSQL 9.5 and Ubuntu 16.04:

```
$ psql -c "\\dt"
```

works fine, while

```
$ psql -c "
> \\dt
> "
```

generates:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 2: \dt
```

Just out of curiosity, when is it OK to insert newlines (i.e. `\n`) into a `psql` command string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***command*** must be either a command string that is completely parsable by the server (i.e., it contains no psql-specific features), or a **single backslash command**.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

It seems that `psql` does not understand a backslash command with the leading new line.

As an alternative you can use piped `echo` command, also described in the documentation. For example:

```
$ echo '
> \d
> select 1 as x;' | psql postgres

        List of relations
 Schema | Name  | Type |  Owner   
--------+-------+------+----------
 public | dummy | view | postgres
(1 row)

 x 
---
 1
(1 row)
```